# Zarankiewicz's problem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

I was reading about Zarankiewicz's problem from the book "Extremal combinatorics" by Stasys Jukna. The problem sounds very interesting and I was about to understand some basics about it. Here I am attaching an excerpt from the book: [image]

**Here is my question:** So we have two objects:

1. the maximal number of $1$'s in a $0-1$ matrix of size $n\times n$ such that any $a\times a$ submatrix has at least one $0$ among its entries. Here we assume that $n\geq a\geq 2$. For concreteness let's denote it by $m_a(n)$.
2. $k_a(n)=\min \mathfrak{C}$, where $\mathfrak{C}$ is the set of all $k \in \mathbb N$ such that any bipartite graph with parts of size $n$ and more than $k$ edges contains at least one $a\times a$ clique.

*Question 1:* 1) I guess that $\min \mathfrak{C}$ exists because $n^2-1\in \mathfrak{C}$. It also shows very trivial estimate $k_a(n)\leq n^2-1$. Right?

*Question 2:* I was able to show that $m_a(n)\leq k_a(n)$. Am I right that we cannot claim the converse inequality, i.e. $m_a(n)\geq k_a(n)$ right?

Comment: $m_a(n)$ and $k_a(n)$ should be equal. Which part of $m_a(n) \ge k_a(n)$ is giving you trouble: the part where we go from matrices to graphs, or the part where one is phrased as a max and the other as a min?

Comment: @MishaLavrov, I think that I got it. At any rate please take a look. We are about to prove that $m_a(n)\geq k_a(n)$. Suppose that $m_a(n)=N$, then it means that the maximal number of $1$'s in $0-1$ matrix of size $n\times n$ with the property (that any submatrix of size $a\times a$ has zero among its entries) is $N$. If we show that $N\in \mathfrak{C}$, then it immediately implies that $k_a(n)\leq N\equiv m_a(n)$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, Fix any bipartite graph $G$ with parts of size $n$ and having $\geq N+1$ edges. For this bipartite we can assign $(0-1)$ matrix which has $\geq N+1$ one's among its entries. By definition of $m_a(n)=N$ there is a submatrix of size $a\times a$ such that all entries are $1$. Hence this graph $G$ has $a\times a$ clique.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, excuse me but does it look correct?

Comment: If you were writing a formal proof, you would have to fill in the details (such as how we form the matrix from $G$) but it looks like you have the idea.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, if graph $G=(V_1,V_2,E)$ is a bipartite graph with parts of size $n$, i.e. $|V_1|=|V_2|=n$ then we can form $0-1$ matrix $M$ as follows: we define $m_{ij}=1$ iff $i$th vertice of $V_1$ is joined with $j$th vertice of $V_2$. So the number of $1$'s in matrix $A$ bsically shows the number of edges in graph $G$. Right?

Comment: @MishaLavrov, and I guess it really important but in all that reasoning we need to assume that $G$ is a simple bipartite graph.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @MishaLavrov, Thanks a lot for your help! I appreciate it!

Comment: @MishaLavrov, May I ask you a question related to twhat which we've discussed? Can I state that $m_a(n)=\max \mathfrak{M}$, where $\mathfrak{M}$ is the set of all $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that any $0-1$ matrix with $k$ ones all submatrices of size $a\times a$ have at least one zero. Is that right?

Comment: No, it's not. You want $\mathfrak M$ to be the set of all $k \in \mathbb N$ such that there *exists* an $n\times n$ binary matrix with $k$ ones where all submatrices of size $a\times a$ have at least one zero.